# Comment blocks with stars in emacs

Tags: emacs, comments

What settings and commands does one need to perform to make comments like this in emacs:

```
  /**
   * 
   * something here
   */
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way is to define your own command for inserting this
comment.  Add this to your .emacs file:

```
(defun insert-doc-comment () (interactive)
   (insert "/**\n * Brief description. Long description. \n * @param \n * @return \n * @exception \n * @see \n * @author \n */"))
```

Then bind the new command to a key of your liking:

```
(define-key global-map [(S-f1)] 'insert-doc-comment)
```

Now pressing Shift-F1 will insert a comment block like this:

```
/**
 * Brief description. Long description. 
 * @param 
 * @return 
 * @exception 
 * @see 
 * @author 
 */
```

Comment: Did as you said. But on pressing Shift+F1, it displays `;2P`. Do you know why?

Comment: Perhaps you're on a terminal which doesn't recognize Shift + function keys. Press `C-h k` and then `S-f1` to see whether Emacs recognizes those keys as `S-f1`.

Comment: Yes, it didn't recognize the Shift key. Modified the key to something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can build templates with emacs. Templates are skeletons for a file structure, and can be tied to files with specific extensions. For example, you can make a java template that applies to any new file you create with a .java extension, and you can make a C++ template that applies to any file you create with a .cpp extension (and another one for .h files if needed).

This [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CppTemplate) has more examples to help you get started with a C++ class template.

Answer (score 2):

Use [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) snipept, if you're not using it yet, try it.

Put this in you snippets/**-mode/

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: dock
# key: /*
# --
/*
 * $1
 */
$0
```

or another version:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: docblock
# key: /**
# --
/**
 * ${1:name} - ${2:short description}
 * @${3:argv1}: $4
 * @${5:argv2}: $6
 *
 * ${7:long description}
 */
$0
```

I got both two in my snippets/, by the way you should copy `yasnippets-xx/snippets` to another place like `~/.emacs.d/snippets`, and put this in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/snippets"))
```

become every time you update yasnippet, the yasnippet-xx/snippets will replaced by the author's snippets, you can `add/delete/modify` your own snippets in `~/.emacs.d/snippets` for your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
M-x customize-group RET comment
```

Look at the "Value Menu" of the "Comment Style" variable.

(Then you can use both "comment-dwim" or "comment-or-uncomment-region" to toggle comments in and out of selected blocks)

You can also use this if you want the current line commented in/out if there is no region active :

```
(defun px-toggle-comments ()
  "If region is set, [un]comments it. Otherwise [un]comments current line."
  (interactive)
  (if (eq mark-active nil)
      (progn 
                (beginning-of-line 1)
                (set-mark (point))
                (forward-line)
                (comment-dwim nil))
    (comment-dwim nil))
  (deactivate-mark))
```

I usually bind it to M-d :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-d") 'px-toggle-comments)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [M-x comment-region](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CommentingCode) and its friends for your particular mode.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems to comment with slashes. I need a combination of slashes and stars (as shown above). How can I customize?

Answer (score -1):

You could define a keyboard macro to do the work, and run it.  For your situation, type out the beginning `/*`, then do `C-x (` then, `C-n M-m *` and, `C-x )`.  Do `C-x e` until the last line that you want to comment out.  When on the last line, end it with a `/`.

I know it looks very ugly, and such, but FWIW, it works for me.  When I have to comment out big blocks, I use this approach.